# How delete the JSESSIONID cookie from the browser with HttpOnly flag set

Tags: java, session-cookies, tomcat8, jsessionid

Apologies if I sound bad.

I have a `xyz.war` that does some authentication and sets a cookie(with `HttpOnly` set so I can not expire it via javascript) so that when the user logs-in for the next time the session is maintained. Now, given that I have the access to the Tomcat that is hosting the `xyz.war` how can I write a Java program that could `expire/delete` the cookie? I can create a `.war` of the java project and host it in the same Tomcat and access it from client side via a api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have invalidate the session in xyz application. Removing (thus beeing able to midify) cookie by third parties would be a security hole.

Comment: I have access to the Tomcat server but I must not change the `xyz.war`

Comment: @IshankDubey Sure, but this is not an option.